# Not Able To Render Single-CustomPostType.php File

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, single

I have CPT and Custom Taxonomy plugin like below

```
function gen_service_tax() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => 'Service Types',
        'singular_name'              => 'Service Type',
        'menu_name'                  => 'Service Types',
        'all_items'                  => 'All Service Types',
        'parent_item'                => 'Service Parent',
        'parent_item_colon'          => 'ServicebParents:',
        'new_item_name'              => 'New Service Name',
        'add_new_item'               => 'Add New Service',
        'edit_item'                  => 'Edit Service',
        'update_item'                => 'Update Service',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate Services with commas',
        'search_items'               => 'Search Services',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove Services',
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used Services',
        'not_found'                  => 'Service Not Found',
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    );
    // This the name tha can be used in Taxonomy cpt collection services
    register_taxonomy( 'services', array( 'services_cpt' ), $args );

}

add_action( 'init', 'gen_service_tax', 0 );

function gen_services_cpt() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                => 'Services',
        'singular_name'       => 'Service',
        'menu_name'           => 'Services',
        'name_admin_bar'      => 'Services',
        'parent_item_colon'   => 'Service Parent:',
        'all_items'           => 'All Services',
        'view_item'           => 'View Service',
        'add_new_item'        => 'Add New Service',
        'add_new'             => 'Add New Service',
        'new_item'            => 'New Service',
        'edit_item'           => 'Edit Service',
        'update_item'         => 'Update Service',
        'search_items'        => 'Search Services',
        'not_found'           => 'Service Not found',
        'not_found_in_trash'  => 'Service Not found in Trash',
    );
    $args = array(
        'description'         => 'This Post Type Adds Services to Website',
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor'),
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'service_tax' ),
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'Services','with_front' => true, 'hierarchical' => true ),
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
    );
    register_post_type( 'services_cpt', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'gen_services_cpt', 0 );
```

I also have this file formats on the theme folder

> single-services.php 
>   single.php 
>   Taxonomy-services.php

[image]

I have also enabled `Post name  http://vancouvermetalworks.ca/sample-post/` option on wp `Permalink Settings` ,as well.
but when I create a new Post type wp navigates first to `single.php` instead of `single-services.php`!
Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You should correct the file names on the theme folder matching with the slugs

Like:

> single-services_cpt.php

Hope you got the error :)

Comment: Thanks Jaed this works but can you please let me know why? as you can see I already register the taxonomy with the name of `services` so why I have to add `_cpt` there?